# BSON in .NET Core 2.0 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman, bson

I have .NET Core WebApi project and I would like send request and get response in BSON.

I installed [`WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson/) and added

```
services.AddMvc().AddBsonSerializerFormatters();
```

in *Startup.cs* in `ConfigureServices`.

Do I need to do anything else?

I have test method in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetTestBson()
{
    return "test string bson";
}
```

I try to test it using Postman, in headers I have `Content-Type: application/bson`
but in response I don't have BSON... I have `"test string bson"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making your request, you need to set a *request* header of `Accept` that is set to `application/bson`:

```
Accept: application/bson
```

By using `Content-Type: application/bson`, you're effectively saying that the request body you're sending is BSON, but as this is a GET request, you're not actually sending a body at all. Using `Accept: application/bson` says that you want BSON to be returned in the response.

This [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers) over at StackExchange's WebMasters explains the difference between `Accept` and `Content-Type` in more detail.

As well as the `Accept` header being required here, you'll also need to return either an object or an array from your action, otherwise the BSON serialiser will fail with a message such as:

> Error writing String value. BSON must start with an Object or Array. Path ''.

In order to return an object, you can do something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetTestBson()
{
    return Ok(new { Value = "test string bson" });
}
```

This returns a new anonymous type with a property of `Value` - you can't just return your existing `string` as an `object`, as a BSON object must have properties.

Comment: Great! now I see in the postman something like "....test....string....bson...." I think is ok? but can I get hex value to check if it works the other way round?

Comment: You might be able to use something like [this](https://json-bson-converter.appspot.com/) for converting from JSON to BSON for testing purposes.